# Namespaced JavasScript code

Tags: javascript

I have the following example app: http://dev.driz.co.uk/jsfunction/

Which runs two types of script files with the same outcome.

Script1:

```
var script1 = {


    showMessage: function( message ) { 

        var el = document.getElementById('example1');

        el.innerHTML = message;

    }
}
```

and script 2:

```
window.script2 = function() {

    function showMessage( message ) {

        var el = document.getElementById('example2');

        el.innerHTML = message;

    }

    return {

        showMessage: showMessage

    }

}();
```

They are both namespaced so I can them like:

```
window.onload = function() {

    script1.showMessage('Hello world!');

    script2.showMessage('How are you?');

};
```

But what's the better way forward? Script1 is the type I would normally write but it requires you to sometimes call a init function first if you have some events that need running on document load.

For example:

```
var script = {

    init: function() {

        // some events such as onlick etc..

    }

};

script.init();
```

Script2 however is a self executing function and therefore would get around this but being a function itself would it allow the same flexibility?

Any thoughts? Suggestions or examples of how people namespace there script files to make them neater and more efficient?

Answer (score 2):

Try module-pattern, or somewhat like the module pattern, using an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

In your case:

```
(function(ns){

  ns.showMessage = function(message){
    var el = document.getElementById('example1');
    el.innerHTML = message;
  }

}(this.script1 = this.script1 || {}));

window.onload = function() {
  script1.showMessage('Hello world!');
};
```

Here's the explanation

```
//basically, an IIFE is a function that executes itself
(function(ns){

  //in here, ns is a reference to our this.namespace

  //also, this IIFE provides us with a local scope
  //we can declare functions and variables that only this scope, by default, sees

  //a "private" variable
  var priv = "I can only be seen in the module";

  //a "private" function
  function privFn(){
    console.log('I am only usable in the module');
  }

  //a "public", or more accurately, an "exposed" variable
  //we attach it to the namespace
  ns.foo = 'I am an exposed value';

  //an exposed function
  ns.bar = function(){
    console.log('exposed!');
    //with an exposed function, we can also call a private function
    privFn();
  }

//this line creates the namespace or uses an existing one
//it then executes the function, passing the created/existing namespace
}(this.namespace = this.namespace || {}));
```

And so, using our module:

```
//we can use the exposed entities
namespace.bar(); 
//exposed! 
//I am only usable in the module <- since bar called privFn, it also prints
namespace.foo === 'I am an exposed value'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on what you need.

For `script1`, every end point can be accessed. `this` can be referenced as the object. I like the pattern like:

```
var Car = {
    name: null,
    init: function (name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
};
```

For `script2`, it encapsulates some private variables or functions, which cannot be accessed outside of the anonymous function scope. You can choose what to expose and what to hide.

```
var Car = (function () {
    var MAX_SPEED = 120; //cannot be referenced

    function init() {
        //something cannot be referenced outside the Car
    }

    function run() {
        //...
    }

    return {
        run: run;
    };

})();
```

These are the ways to create simple namespaces. Because you can also make namespace into a module.

```
namespace("GLOBAL.app.Ticker");
```

`namespace` will be a simple module to parse the string `GLOBAL.app.Ticker`, and convert it to a new Object.